# How to change a color of a navbar item when user clicks on it?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a task to change the first-level item in my navbar on pink when I hover it and the second-level ones should be pink by default and blue when I hover them.

In reality, color of the first level hovered one wasn't change, color of the second unhovered one is ok, and of the 2nd hovered works without changing.

here is my code:

```
html .nav .item .dropdown,
body .nav .item .dropdown,
html .nav .item .dropdown-menu,
body .nav .item .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: HotPink;
}

html .nav .item .dropdown .active:hover,
body .nav .item .dropdown .active:hover,
html .nav .item .dropdown-menu .active:hover,
body .nav .item .dropdown-menu .active:hover,
html .nav .item .dropdown .inside_item,
body .nav .item .dropdown .inside_item,
html .nav .item .dropdown-menu .inside_item,
body .nav .item .dropdown-menu .inside_item {
  text-transform: none;
}
html .nav .item .dropdown .active:hover:hover,
body .nav .item .dropdown .active:hover:hover,
html .nav .item .dropdown-menu .active:hover:hover,
body .nav .item .dropdown-menu .active:hover:hover,
html .nav .item .dropdown .inside_item:hover,
body .nav .item .dropdown .inside_item:hover,
html .nav .item .dropdown-menu .inside_item:hover,
body .nav .item .dropdown-menu .inside_item:hover {
  background-color: lightSkyBlue;
```

What to do to make them work?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522555/changing-bootstrap-navbar-color) maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple and straightforward.

It should look something like this;

/* normal state */

```
.dropdown {
background-color: //color;
}
```

if you want to change the **color of dropdown** when you hover you add;

```
.dropdown:hover {
background-color: //color;
}
```

If you go a level deeper;

```
.dropdown .active {
//color
}
```

and if you want to change the bg-color on hover;

```
.dropdown .active:hover {
//color}
```